# Where to put API keys for Twitter app on server

Tags: ruby, security, twitter, server, directory-structure

I'm currently writing a couple Twitter bots for my friends using the Twitter gem for Ruby. My plan was to store the keys for them in a .txt file with the rest of the bot's code on my server, but everything I've read has said the keys shouldn't be readable within the code. Is this secure enough, and if not what would be a good solution? Thanks!

Comment: what platform are you using for hosting?

Comment: you can save it as env variable just call it in the code where you need it `ENV["TWITTER_API"]`

Comment: @maxpleaner I'm using a Debian 9 droplet on DigitalOcean

Comment: @icemelt Are environment variables tied to the directory or do they exist across the entire server? Forgive me, I'm still fairly new to Unix/Linux.

Comment: its tied to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach is to save the environment variables into a file called `.env` that is ignored by version control (and therefore won't be included on Github)  but read by the code. One gem to help with this is [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv).

1. add `.env` to the `.gitignore` file.
2. create a local `.env` file with all your env vars
3. `require 'dotenv'` and put `Dotenv.load` somewhere at the beginning of your script. In Rails, the `require` is unnecessary and you can place the load call in any file in the `config/initializers` folder
4. Check that your app works fine locally. The environment variables should be found in the `ENV` hash from Ruby code.
5. Save changes and push new version of app to digital ocean
6. manually create the .env file on the digital ocean server, in the root of the repo
7. run digital ocean server and check that everything works.

other notes:

- see [How To Read and Set Environmental and Shell Variables on a Linux VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-a-linux-vps)
- some platforms like heroku have a different mechanism for setting environment variables, such as `heroku config:set` or web UIs.
- You can set environment variables on a one-off basis using the `env` command in bash, for example:

  ```
  env a=hello b=' world' ruby -e 'puts ENV["a"] + ENV["b"]'
  # => hello world
  ```

  This can give a quick way to configure a program without getting into argument parsing. For example in Rails, you can say `rails c test` to open a console using the test environment, but `env RAILS_ENV=test rails c` should do the same thing.